# When trying call guard let self throwing an error

Tags: swift, xcode14.3

Up until now I'm able to use:

```
button.tapHandler = { [weak self] _ in 
   guard let self else { return }
   self.dismiss()
}
```

but after upgrading to Xcode 14.3 and Swift 5.8 it no longer works. It throws an error:

> implicit use of `self` in closure; use `self.` to make capture semantics explicits

Does the shortcut no longer work in the Swift 5.8?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Strange. I checked whether this was a change in Swift 5.8, but it's not listed in the [changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md). In fact, one of the code examples in the changelog for 5.8 has `guard let self else { return }`, so it's clearly meant to be valid.

Comment: On the contrary, not only does `guard let self` work, but you can then omit the `self` in `self.dismiss()`.

Comment: There might be something _else_ wrong with your code, elsewhere, that causes _this_ code to generate a false error message. But you have not, as has been pointed out, shown enough info for anyone to reproduce the problem you claim to be having.

Comment: yes, i think that would be the case. We are able to pinpoint it happens on our internal frameworks that use @resultbuilder and Rx only.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.3 have a new feature - implicit `self` now permitted after unwrapping `self`

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 14.3, you no longer have to explicitly reference `self` after unwrapping.  Change the code to

```
button.tapHandler = { [weak self] _ in 
   guard let self else { return }
   dismiss()
}
```